# How come I cannot fetch the name of the taxonomy term from term id?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, hooks

We are using the following code to fetch all the taxonomy term values in the *term_category* vocabulary.

```php
$db = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();
$term_categories = $db->query('select tid, vid from taxonomy_term_data where vid ='\'term_category\'');

foreach($term_categories as $category) {
  $category_term = (\Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($category->tid));
  ksm($category_term->label()); // returns NULL.
  ksm($category_term->getName()); // returns NULL. 
}
```

When we run it, we get `NULL` as label.

The *Article* content type has a *field_category* field that is an entity reference for the *term_category* vocabulary. Currently, no *Article* node has any value populated for that field, as it is optional.

Why I cannot get the taxonomy term name from its ID?

Comment: `label()` is more generic.  Forget about `getName()`.  See [Deprecate Node::getTitle() & other entity-type-specific calls in favour of Entity::label()](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2921988) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your problem is that you're trying to call entity class methods on a `stdClass` object - directly querying the database means you're not using the API any more, the results you get aren't entities.

Unless there's a particular reason to do so, though, you shouldn't have to do it that way.

For example, the same query can be executed like this through the API:

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
  ->loadByProperties(['vid' => 'term_category']);

foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $name = $term->getName();
}
```

It's quicker (loading in one go, not single loads in a loop), fewer lines of code, and when you bring caching into it, probably more performant.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$term_category = 'term_category';
$term_data = [];
  $terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($term_category);
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_data[] = array(
      'title' => $term->name,
      'description' => $term->description
    );
  }
ksm($terms);
```

Comment: when I ran this, the foreach loop ran 77 times where only 15 had values and all others returned `NULL`. However, i found my issue to be that i needed to switch to `taxonomy_term_field_data`

Comment: Try the second Way.

Comment: the second way did work, can you update your answer to reflect this so it is easier for others if they come across this?

Answer (score 1):

The `Term` object has a method for `getName` and `label`.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Entity%21Term.php/function/Term%3A%3AgetName/8.6.x

Therefore, if this is a real term entity, it will have a name accessible via `getName`.

You should debug `$category` in the loop to see you are accessing the right property.

Comment: I was indeed accessing the wrong property on the wrong entity. I was able to get it to work when switching tables from `taxonomy_term_data` to `taxonomy_term_field_data`

Comment: Looking at it holistically rather than just switching tables, I ended up following Clive's suggestion

Comment: That was going to be my second suggestion, after you resolved the first issue so you saw why.

Comment: `getName()` won't be around too much longer.  See [Deprecate Node::getTitle() & other entity-type-specific calls in favour of Entity::label()](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2921988).